# Why does the Biot-Savart law give the induced velocity of a infinitesimal segment of a vortex filament at point P?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, fluid-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, vortex

My question is about the proof of how the Biot-Savart law can be used for vortex filaments. This is what I have in my textbook:
[image]

However, I'm not certain how it was derived - I understand that the Biot-Savart law originally came from electromagnetic theory, but could anyone present the proof for it's use for vortex filaments?

Intuitively though, something seems off - a vortex filament is just made out of lots of individual vortexes put together in a filament, so shouldn't the induced velocity at a point P of an infinitesimal section of the filament be zero unless $d\vec{l}$ and $\vec{r}$ are perpendicular... but clearly it's not the case,
$$
 d\vec{V} = \frac{ d\vec{l} \times  \vec{r} }{ \lvert \vec{r} \lvert ^3}
$$
, which is nonzero even when $d\vec{l}$ and $\vec{r}$ aren't perpendicular

Comment: I think this might be a better fit for [physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). The vortices may be related to aviation, but proving a theorem is better suited for physics.

Comment: The whoda whatzit law for vortex what-the-hecks?  Over my head...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys, I **finally** found a proof for this, after a long time of googling:

https://www.whoi.edu/fileserver.do?id=218347&pt=10&p=116694

Basically, you use the differential definition of vorticity (w=curl of velocity) and the incompressibility condition (divergence of velocity = 0), then combine them and solve.

Comment: Can you please summarize the results into your answer? Otherwise, it defies the purpose of SE.

Answer (score 0):

Why would

> the induced velocity at a point P of an infinitesimal section of the filament be zero unless $d\vec{l}$ and $\vec{r}$ are perpendicular

?

The cross product in
$$
 \frac{ d\vec{l} \times  \vec{r} }{ \lvert \vec{r} \lvert ^3}
$$

does not change signs when going over the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ angle in between vectors, so the infinitesimal filament sections $d\vec{l^-}$ (immediately before $d\vec{l}$) and $d\vec{l^+}$ (immediately after $d\vec{l}$) have contributions to $d\vec{V}$ that do not cancel each other out. Therefore, $\vec{V}$ is not just a function of a single filament section, but of the entire filament, hence the integral.

If you check the next section in the [source of your image](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/SPRING/fluids/Spring2008/LectureNotes/f06.pdf), titled **Straight-vortex case** you will see this in action.

Comment: Nevermind, I found a proof for it:

https://www.whoi.edu/fileserver.do?id=218347&pt=10&p=116694